# How should I go about storing my Xaml code for multiple windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menuitem

I am working with a menu(File, options, etc). I have click events for them with the code to do what I want them to do. This is all for the main window at the moment though and it seems tedious to copy/paste the code to another windows .xaml.cs file.

Am I able to store this xaml code in a separate c# file so I don't need to have all the click events in the MainWindow.Xaml.cs? And allow me to use the same click events for the menu over multiple windows?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to turn your menu into a [UserControl](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xaml/xaml_custom_controls.htm) that can be reused in multiple windows.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, Thanks!  Still learning all the syntax so I find myself not knowing what to search for lol.